# Validating image attributes in Strict 1.0 -

Tags: image, validation, xhtml-1.0-strict

I'm creating my very first webpage, and I hope someone can help!

I'm trying to validate a page in Strict, but I'm told that these attributes aren't valid:

```
align="left" hspace="10px"
```

Is there any way I can get the same results in a way that will validate?

Many thanks from an absolute beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`style="margin-left:10px"` is probably what you're after.

However `hspace="10px"` might not have been putting the extra space there at all as it should just be `hspace="10"`.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS, you can accomplish the same thing. You'll want to learn as much as you can about CSS, as you'll be needing it a lot. I would suggest starting with an introductory tutorial.

- http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

Depending on how your HTML looks, you can align the `img` with CSS properties such as `float` and `text-align`. For spacing around the image you can use `padding` and `margin` (probably padding in this scenario).

Comment: Many thanks, that's brilliant - float was just what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Usually XHTML 1.0 Transitional is good enough, and you don't need to go for Strict.

If you really need Strict, you can do it with css.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do need Strict for this, but many thanks for the advice.